# How to add to an earlier commit some changes I inadvertently omitted?

Tags: git, version-control

#### Problem

Halfway through a coding session, I usually realize there are some changes that should have been made together with an earlier commits (usually something like renaming items or typos).

#### Question

What is the cleanest and most straightforward way to add the changes that I inadvertently omitted back to the earlier commit?

#### Current Approach

My current approach is as follows:

1. Make the omitted changes, commit with the message `FIXMEUP`  :

```sh
> git commit -m "FIXMEUP"
```

2. Stash remaining changes with:

```sh
> git stash
```

3. Find the hash (let's call it  for now) for commit that the change should have been made in

```sh
> git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --pretty=oneline
```

4. Do an interactive rebase (note that the `^` is required to refer to the commit itself):

```sh
> git rebase -i <hash>^
```

5. In the interactive rebase, move the `FIXMEUP` commit to just after the commit with `<hash>`, and change the rebase action from `pick` to `fixup`.

Comment: Everything is ok. Automate this with alias `git fixup <hash>`. See https://blog.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/ and https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/04410eab725ef152e1eb70a87cb6fd4f52f7b4ea/gitalias.txt#L314. Full disclosure: I'm a contributor to GitAlias.

Comment: @JakeWorth, thanks for pointing me to the GitAlias project. Definitely good see what commands that other people are commonly using but I'm not 

Answer (score 1):

This workflow make sense; I can only think of one way do it more directly.

First, figure out the commit you want to fixup your changes on. Your `git log` command should show that.

Then, when you commit, use the `--fixup` flag:

```sh
$ git commit --fixup <target commit>
```

When you run your interactive rebase, it will look like this:

```
pick <target commit> First commit
fixup a3213d3 fixup! First commit
pick a7d34ae Second commit
```

You've saved yourself from having to write a throwaway commit message on the fixup commit, and from editing the interactive rebase manifest-- it's already prepped to fixup the change.